# Google Cloud Speech API streaming limit at 65 seconds, not 5 minutes

Tags: c#, google-cloud-speech

I am using Google's Cloud Speech API in C# to stream input from a microphone and output text.  It works well up to the point where it crashes at 65 seconds, with the error saying that there's a 65 minute request limit.  This website https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas says that my limit should be about 5 minutes.  The function I used is below, and the seconds parameter is how long the stream is requested to last.  Am I using old methods or could it be because I'm on the free trial version for the API key?

I've seen other Stack Overflow questions similar to this, and they link to the same website saying the streaming limit is supposed to be about one minute, yet the site has updated within the last year and a half but my limit is still one minute.

```
public static async Task<object> StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(int seconds)
    {
        if (NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No microphone!");
            return -1;
        }
        var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
        var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();
        // Write the initial request with the config.
        await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
            new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
            {
                StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
                {
                    Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                    {
                        Encoding =
                        RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                        SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                        LanguageCode = "en",
                    },
                    InterimResults = true,
                }
            });
        // Print responses as they arrive.
        Task printResponses = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
                default(CancellationToken)))
            {
                foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream
                    .Current.Results)
                {
                    foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                    {
                        if (alternative.Confidence != 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Read from the microphone and stream to API.
        object writeLock = new object();
        bool writeMore = true;
        var waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
        waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
        waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 1); //(hertz, channels)
        waveIn.DataAvailable +=
            (object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs args) =>
            {
                lock (writeLock)
                {
                    if (!writeMore) return;
                    streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                        new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                        {
                            AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString
                                .CopyFrom(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded)
                        }).Wait();
                }
            };
        waveIn.StartRecording();
        Console.WriteLine("Speak now.");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        waveIn.StopRecording();
        lock (writeLock) writeMore = false;
        await streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
        await printResponses;
        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: A product manager from Google replied to my post on a Google discussion page.  He said that the 5 minutes advertised is a mistake, yet they are planning on extending the streaming limit soon.  Is there a clean way to make multiple streaming requests that are within the 65 second limit yet also doesn't miss the user's speaking or cut words in half between requests?

Comment: Which version of Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 are you using? And could you provide the complete exception? I'll try to reproduce this, although I'll have to get the NAudio bits working...

Comment: I have version 1.0.1 of Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 installed, here's the libraries I'm using as well:
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

And the error is: "An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: One or more errors occurred."
In details, it says: "Exceeded maximum allowed stream duration of 65 seconds" under Inner Exceptions

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to reproduce this, and ask internally.

Comment: Whoops, I hadn't seen your edit when I added the previous comment. It sounds like it's not worth me testing right now - it's "expected" to fail. I don't know of any way of effectively chunking the stream, I'm afraid. There's a lot of context that's used within the speech recognition, which would be missing from the next request.